# Does $(T_n f)(x) = n( f(x+1/n) -f(x) )$ converges on operator norm, $T_n: C^1 [0,1] \to C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

> Does the sequence $T_n: C^1 [0,1]\to C[0,1]$, $(T_n f)(x):=n(f(x+1/n)-f(x))\,\forall x\in[0,1]$, converge in operator norm?

I found that it converges pointwise to $f'(x)$ and tried looking at $(T_nf)(x)=n\int_x^{x+1/n}f'(t)dt$ hence

$\|T_nf-T_0 f\|=\|n\int_x^{x+1/n}f'(t)dt-f'(x)\| = n\|\int_x^{x+1/n}f'(t)-f'(x)dt\|\to 0, n \to \infty. $

$\|T_nf-f'\|_{op} = \sup_{f\in C^1[0,1], f\neq 0} \frac{\|T_nf-f'\|_{\infty}}{\|f\|_{C^1}} = \sup_{f\in C^1[0,1], f\neq 0} \frac{\|T_nf-f'\|_{\infty}}{\max|f|+|f'|}$

Let $f = x^m,$ hence $n\to \infty$

$||T_nf-f'||_{op} \to \infty$

Therefore $T_n$ does not converge in operator norm.

Am I wrong? Could you please advise me?

Comment: To begin with, $∫_x^{x+1/n}f'(x)dx$ makes no sense. Replace it  with $∫_x^{x+1/n}f'(t)dt.$ Even so (and assuming that the two $||g(x)||$ mean $||x\mapsto g(x)||$), your second equality is wrong.

Comment: Replace it with $||n∫_x^{x+1/n}f'(t)dt-f'(x)||=n||∫_x^{x+1/n}(f'(t)-f'(x))dt||.$ To end the proof, use that $f'$ is uniformly continuous. The conclusion must be that the limit is $0,$ not $\infty.$ Btw, you forgot to define $T_0.$

Comment: But this won't prove that $T_n\to T_0$ in operator norm. It will only prove the weak convergence.

Comment: What should I do to prove in operator norm?

Comment: What do you mean by $f(x+1/n)$ when $x>1-1/n$ ?

Comment: $x\in [0,1],$ we can get smooth continuation to $\mathbb{R}$ and i think it whould change nothing what is the value of f, hence we could make $f(x+1/n) \equiv 0$ when x>1−1/n

Comment: Your recent edit should be suppressed. You are on the wrong floor. The operator norm should not apply to $T_nf-f'$ (which is not an operator but a function on $[0,1]$) but to $T_n-D$ (where $Df=f'$), and your quotient $\sup_{x \ne0} \frac{||T_nf-f'||}{||x||}$ makes no sense (the numerator does not depend on $x$, and we don't know who is $x$: a vector (since you take its norm) or a real number). $\|T_n-D\|_{op}=\sup_{f\in C^1[0,1],f\ne0}\frac{\|T_nf-f'\|_\infty}{\|f\|_{C^1}},$ where $\|~\|_{C^1}$ still needs to be specified (there are various natural equivalent norms on $C^1[0,1]$).

Comment: I may be wrong but I do not believe that $\|T_n-D\|_{op}\to0.$ Were you told to prove it? Is this exercise from a book?

Comment: just an exercise from my friend, I want to deal with this topic, because I don't well understand it, if you have some exercises for better understanding i whould be pleased you share

Comment: `\infty` renders $\infty$

Comment: `\|` renders $\|$ properly and `\max,\sup` are already supported commands: `\operatorname{}` is a useful tool but was not needed here

Comment: Also, it's all very well saying $f(x+1/n)\equiv0$ when $x>1-1/n$ but that could break continuity, and you'll need to *fix a choice* of continuous extension for *all* $f$ (and $n$) in order for the $(T_n)$ to be well defined. That requires a silly amount of choice and you'd need to ensure the result is independent of the choices made

Comment: Again: $||T_nf-f'||_{op}$ (which you still wrote twice) is nonsense. The operator norm should not apply to a function on $[0,1].$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to avoid the problem with extensions let $S_n, \,S_0:C^1[0,2]\to C[0,1]$ be defined by
$$(S_nf)(x)=n[f(x+n^{-1})-f(x)],\quad (S_0f)(x)=f'(x)$$ The space $C^1[0,2]$ will be equipped with the norm $$\|f\|=|f(0)|+\|f'\|_\infty$$ This norm is equivalent to the norm $\|\,|f|+|f'|\,\|_\infty$ mentioned in OP.
Then $\|S_n-S_0\|\le \|T_n-T_0\|.$ We are going to show that $\|S_n-S_0\|$ does not tend to $0.$ Let $f_a(x)={1\over 2}\sin( 2ax),$ $a\ge 1.$  Then $\|f_a\|_{C^1}= a.$    On the other hand
$$(S_nf_a)(x)-(S_0f_a)(x)\\ =n\sin(a/n)\cos(2ax+a/n)-a\cos(2ax) $$
For $x_a={\pi\over 4a}$ we get $$ (S_nf_a)(x_a)-(S_0f_a)(x_a)=-n\sin^2(a/n)$$ Thus
$$\|S_n-S_0\|\ge {\|S_nf_a-S_0f_a\|\over \|f_a\|}\ge {n\sin^2(a/n)\over a} $$ For $a:={\pi n\over 2 }$ we get
$$\|S_n-S_0\|\ge {2\over \pi}$$

Comment: @AnneBauval Right. Just now I have noticed that the norm in OP is different  than the one I use.

Comment: @AnneBauval I have decided to take still another norm to simplify calculations: $|f(0)|+\|f'\|_\infty.$

Comment: Fine! May be just mention that these norms are equivalent.

Comment: (+1) always a pleasure to read your solutions.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thanks Oliver.